# Format SQL result into array; access by key?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I have a table with items with a `name` and `id`. Here's some `create table` code:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id INT,
    name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO items VALUES
    (1, "Flute"),
    (2, "Guitar"),
    (4, "Saxophone"),
    (7, "Tuba"),
    (5, "Xylophone"),
    (14, "Triangle");
```

I want to perform a query on this grabbing all items:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT id, name FROM items
    ORDER BY id ASC
");
$stmt->execute();
$items = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This creates an array that looks something like the below:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ([id] => 1, [name] => "Flute"),
    [1] => Array ([id] => 2, [name] => "Guitar"),
    ...
    [5] => Array ([id] => 14, [name] => "Triangle")
)
```

I want to access this array by key `id`. Something like:

```
echo $array["1"]; // "Flute"
echo $array["14"]; // "Triangle"
echo $array["7"]; // "Tuba"
```

Not necessarily exactly like the above, but in a way that I can print `name` from the array by using key `id`. Is something like this possible? To format the array created earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a new array and iterate over the old.

Something like:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $item)
    $newArray[$item['id']] = $item['name']
```